# Is a Standard Tableau determined by its descent set?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions, young-tableaux

Suppose $\lambda\vdash n$ is a partition. Associated with this partition is the set of [Standard Young Tableau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) $\text{SYT}(\lambda)$ such that the associated Young Diagram is filled in with the numbers $\{1,\dots,n\}$, with rows and columns strictly increasing.

For example, if $\lambda=(3,2)$, the Young Tableaux of this shape are given by
$$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5\end{matrix},
\quad\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 5\end{matrix},
\quad\begin{matrix}1 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 5\end{matrix},
\quad\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 4\end{matrix},
\quad\begin{matrix}1 & 3 & 5 \\ 2 & 4\end{matrix}$$
The element $i$ is in the *descent set* of a tableau if $i+1$ occurs strictly below $i$. Hence, the descent sets of the above are
$$\{3\},\quad\quad\{2,4\},\quad\quad\{1,4\},\quad\quad\{2\},\quad\quad\{1,3\}$$
and we can see that each of these are distinct.

My question then applies to the general case. For a given partition $\lambda\vdash n$, are the descent sets of the standard tableaux in $\text{SYT}(\lambda)$ dinstinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the partition $\lambda=\langle 3,2,2,1\rangle$. It has standard Young tableaux

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1&3&4\\
2&7\\
5&8\\
6
\end{array}\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&3&4\\
2&5\\
6&7\\
8
\end{array}$$

Both of these have descent set $\{1,4,5,7\}$.

Comment: Prof. Scott are you coming back to this site?

Comment: @ILoveMath: I’m afraid that I’m not likely to return any time soon: I left partly because of increased demands on my time elsewhere that have priority and partly because of increasing frustration with The Powers That Be and the way that certain things are handled here, and neither of those seems likely to change in the foreseeable future. I am continuing to respond to pings and to fix typos (or worse errors!) in old answers when I see them, and I did answer one question because I was specifically requested to look at it and able to find the time to do so, but that’s about it.

Comment: Teacher can you take a look at this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338592/calculus-exercise-prove-there-is-an-integer-such-that