# Calculus exercise: Prove there is an integer such that

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Problem: Given $\epsilon>0, x >0$, prove that there exists $n \in
>  \mathbb{N}$ so that $n \epsilon > x$.

Attempt:

If not, we can select $\epsilon>0$ and $x>0$ so that $n \epsilon \leq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We observe that the set $A = \{ n \epsilon : n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{ \epsilon, 2 \epsilon, 3 \epsilon, .... \}$ is bounded, namely $x$ is a bound and so $\alpha = \sup A$ exists. Clearly $\alpha - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound and thus there is some $n_o$ positive integer so that

$$ n_o \epsilon >\alpha - \epsilon \implies \epsilon(n_0 +1 ) > \alpha $$

But this means that $\alpha$ is not an upper bound as $\epsilon(n_0+1) \in A$. This contradiction establishes the problem.

Question: Is this solution correct? I would mainly to have some criticism or logic mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Looks just fine.

Comment: Or more constructively: $\dfrac x\epsilon$ is defined and bounded so there is a larger natural.

Comment: This smells quite similar to Rudin's proof, so it's probably correct...

Comment: It’s fine, assuming that you have the completeness axiom that justifies the existence of $\alpha$.